# Как из одного powershell скрипта запустить другой?

Tags: powershell

Есть a.ps1 и b.ps1 в папке C:\scripts
Как из одного powershell скрипта (a.ps1) запустить другой (b.ps1) в своем процессе powershell? (чтоб параметры первого не повлияли на параметры второго).

Comment: Приветствую. Вроде был где-то. [Раз](https://superuser.com/questions/881853/how-to-execute-a-ps1-from-another-ps1-file) и [Два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816450/call-powershell-script-ps1-from-another-ps1-script-inside-powershell-ise)

Comment: да, первый я видел. он не работает почему то. пишет ошибку: Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

PS это командная оболочка
в первый файл нужно добавить

```
start powershell .\b.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

В a.ps1 надо надо всего лишь [добавить &](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-):

```
& .\b.ps1
```